# Measuring the distance between points on arcGis

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis, arcmap

help me please, it is necessary to put a point on the map and measure the distance on arcGis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the Measure tool on the toolbar.](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00s500000022000000)

[image: Image of ArcMap measure tool results]

Comment: it is necessary to put points a and b (an example of this would be the beginning of a street and the end of the street) and determine the distances. this is how to do?

Comment: If you're asking something more specific, then you will need to edit your original question to include more detail.